# Ordenar div en columnas

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

Estoy desarrollando una web en la que tengo un `<div>` (de tamaño fijo) y le voy añadiendo pequeños `<div>` mediante JavaScript con `appendChild()`.

El caso es que no consigo hacer lo que quiero, mi idea es que se vayan añadiendo de la siguiente forma:

```
----------------------------------------------
|              |              |              |
|      1º      |      5º      |      9º      |
|              |              |              |
----------------------------------------------
|              |              |              |
|      2º      |      6º      |      10º     |
|              |              |              |
----------------------------------------------
|              |              |              |
|      3º      |      7º      |      11º     |
|              |              |              |
----------------------------------------------
|              |              |              |
|      4º      |      8º      |      12º     |
|              |              |              |
----------------------------------------------
```

Tal cual, que vaya creando columnas de 4 filas.

A ver si alguien puede echarme una mano.

¡Gracias por adelantado!

Comment: Sin ver tu código es complicado ayudarte, pero usando algo como `height: 25%;width:33.3%` debería solucionar el problema

Comment: @blonfu probé con display: flex, que creo que es a lo que te refieres pero se colocaban uno al lado de otro simplelente (creo recordar, he probado tantas cosas)

Comment: @PabloLozano nada, probé y el mismo resultado, y probé a flotar cada item y si, se hacían columnas pero se hacia primero una fila de 4 columnas, y luego otra fila. Mi intención es primero una columna de 4 filas, y luego crear otra columna

Comment: @blonfu no me funcionó, sigo obteniendo lo mismo, al no ser que me sobre algo en mi css...

Comment: @blonfu Eso es! Muchísimas gracias!

Comment: Hola @Jmyebenes Me alegra que la solucion propuesta por blonfu funcionara. Sin embargo, el formato del sitio hace que las respuestas tengan que estár en la seccion de respuestas, no en los comentarios ni como edit en la pregunta. Asi que has de quitar esa parte de la pregunta donde indicas que está solucionado y esperar a que Blonfu añada la respuesta para que la aceptes. Un saludo

Comment: @lois6b Ya, claro, pero como no lo hizo, qué menos que agradecérselo por ahí y facilitando a los interesados en hacer algo similar a encontrar la respuesta en vez de buscar entre los comentarios. Si lo pone como respuesta la aceptaré y quitaré eso de la pregunta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Por defecto los elementos HTML se ordenan de izquierda a derecha pero con CSS podemos cambiar ese orden a nuestro gusto. La forma que nos ofrece más posibilidades y también la más sencilla, para mí al menos, es flexbox.

Hace falta un contenedor que tenga `flex` como valor de la propiedad `display` y decirle que ordene en columnas en lugar de filas y hacer que se los elementos se ajusten a su contenedor con `flex-wrap:wrap`. También hay que ajustar la altura para que entre solo el número de cajas que deseamos y después es ir jugando con la propiedad `flex` y las alineaciones según lo que deseemos conseguir.

Aquí un ejemplo de como podría ser:

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 208px;
  border: solid 1px red;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: flex-start;
}

.create-route {
  width: 50px;
  flex: 0 1 50px;
  background-color: white;
  border: solid 1px #1c4051;
  border-radius: 6px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="create-route">
    1
  </div>
  <div class="create-route">
    2
  </div>
  <div class="create-route">
    3
  </div>
  <div class="create-route">
    4
  </div>
  <div class="create-route">
    5
  </div>
  <div class="create-route">
    6
  </div>
  <div class="create-route">
    7
  </div>
  <div class="create-route">
    8
  </div>
  <div class="create-route">
    9
  </div>
  <div class="create-route">
    10
  </div>
  <div class="create-route">
    11
  </div>
  <div class="create-route">
    12
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Genial @blonfu  muchas gracias por tu ayuda!

Answer (score 1):

**GRID**

Usa [grid](https://lenguajecss.com/p/css/propiedades/grid-css) de css para dividir los divs en "celdas".

Aqui te dejo un ejemplo.

```css
.grid {
  display:grid;
  grid-template-areas: "head head"
                       "menu main"
                       "foot foot";
}

.a { grid-area:head; background:blue }
.b { grid-area:menu; background:red }
.c { grid-area:main; background:green }
.d { grid-area:foot; background:orange }
```

```html
<div class="grid"> <!-- contenedor -->
  <div class="a">Item 1</div> <!-- cada uno de los ítems del grid -->
  <div class="b">Item 2</div>
  <div class="c">Item 3</div>
  <div class="d">Item 4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Claro, pero ahí creas un css diferente para cada div teniendo 4, pero yo los genero con JavaScript y pueden ser muchísimos, tendría que crear una regla para cada uno, saber cuantos divs he añadido para saber donde colocarlo y demás..

Comment: son clases, y por lo que veo en tu ejemplo, van a ser iguales. Dales la misma clase a todos.

Answer (score 0):

Creando primero columnas y añadiendo elementos a éstas, puedes hacer algo como lo siguiente:

```css
#container {
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
  position: relative;
}
.columna {
  width: 33%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  
}
.columna div {
  height: 25%;
  width: 99%;
  margin: 5px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="columna">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
   <div class="columna">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
  
   <div class="columna">
   
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```